# import side effects on logging: how to reset the logging module?

Tags: python, logging, import

Consider this code:

```
import logging
print "print"
logging.error("log")
```

I get:

```
print
ERROR:root:log
```

now if I include a thid-party module at the beginning of the previous code and rerun it I get only:

```
print
```

there are some previous question about this, but here I cannot touch the module I'm importing.

The code of the third-party module is here: http://atlas-sw.cern.ch/cgi-bin/viewcvs-atlas.cgi/offline/DataManagement/DQ2/dq2.clientapi/lib/dq2/clientapi/DQ2.py?view=markup, but my question is more general: independently of the module I'm importing I want a clean `logging` working in the expected way

**Some (non-working) proposed solutions:**

```
from dq2.clientapi.DQ2 import DQ2
import logging
del logging.root.handlers[:]
```

---

```
from dq2.clientapi.DQ2 import DQ2
import logging
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

---

```
logs = logging.getLogger('root')
logs.error("Some error")
```

---

the next one works, but produced some additional errors:

```
from dq2.clientapi.DQ2 import DQ2
import logging
reload(logging)
```

I get:

```
print
ERROR:root:log
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/external/Python/2.6.5/x86_64-slc5-gcc43-    opt/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/external/Python/2.6.5/x86_64-slc5-gcc43-opt/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in shutdown
    h.close()
  File "/afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/external/Python/2.6.5/x86_64-slc5-gcc43-opt/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 705, in close
    del _handlers[self]
KeyError: <logging.StreamHandler instance at 0x2aea031f7248>
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/external/Python/2.6.5/x86_64-slc5-gcc43-opt/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/external/Python/2.6.5/x86_64-slc5-gcc43-opt/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in shutdown
    h.close()
  File "/afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/external/Python/2.6.5/x86_64-slc5-gcc43-opt/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 705, in close
    del _handlers[self]
KeyError: <logging.StreamHandler instance at 0x2aea031f7248>
```

---

```
from dq2.clientapi.DQ2 import DQ2
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()  
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.error("log")
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "if I include a module at the beginning" ?

Comment: I was expecting this comment, and every time I'm surprised. Do I really need to put a sentence ending with a question mark? Is it not clear my problem?

Comment: apparently not. i understand that there is some error, but what exactly do you want help with?

Comment: @BasicWolf: at the top of the previous three lines code

Comment: @wiso I can't reproduce your problem. E.g. `import os` before those lines of code has no effect like one you've described.

Comment: "if I include a module at the beginning" - any module or some specific module?

Comment: @BasicWolf: yes, of course because the `os` module is well written. I'm talking about a third party module, I cannot post it

Comment: @wiso Oh! My libtelepathy.so is probably outdated, that's why I can't see the code of your 3d party module. No offense, but just get into that library and see what the heck it does with logging. I'd advice to close the question as unconstructive.

Comment: Apparently the third party module must be initializing loggers, so your logging behaviour will get modified. You should get a handle to the intialized logger and then use that instead of using `logging.error()`

Comment: @RedBaron: a specific module, if you're interested is this one: http://atlas-sw.cern.ch/cgi-bin/viewcvs-atlas.cgi/offline/DataManagement/DQ2/dq2.clientapi/lib/dq2/clientapi/DQ2.py?view=markup, but I think it's too long to read all the code and its includes

Comment: try this `logs = logging.getLogger('root') logs.error("Some error")`

Comment: @BasicWolf: I've posted the module, by the way my question is more general, not module specific, you don't need any telepathy features. I need a way to have a clean logging object without knowing anything about the imported module

Comment: @RedBaron: thanks, but doesn't work

Comment: Actually the module modifies the root logger and sends the logs to some other place, so any use of logging.error() will log messages to wherever the module designer configured the root level to go. You can create a new logger, add a streamHandler and thenuse that logger to log your messages

Comment: please motivate downvote

Comment: fyi: the pip package is such a culprit. Well, it is if you call it's `main` method, which appears to be the only way to use pip programmatically (as of pip 9.0.1).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It depends on what the other module is doing; e.g. if it's calling `logging.disable` then you can call `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)` to reset it.

You could try reloading the `logging` module:

```
from importlib import reload
logging.shutdown()
reload(logging)
```

The problem is this will leave the third-party module with its own copy of `logging` in an unusable state, so could cause more problems later.

Comment: `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)` doesn't work, `reload(logging)` works, but produce additional errors (see at the edit in the post)

Comment: @wiso try calling `logging.shutdown()` before `reload(logging)`.

Comment: OK! here we are, thank you, it works. Fortunately I've no error from the thid-party module, by the way I've opened a bug ticket

Comment: It seems a terrible design that logging settings affects all loggers. Sure it's easy to turn off all logging, but it's really messy to work with.

Comment: I am having following error `AttributeError: 'RootLogger' object has no attribute 'shutdown'`

Answer (score 17):

To completely clear existing logging configuration from the root logger, this might work:

```
root = logging.getLogger()
list(map(root.removeHandler, root.handlers))
list(map(root.removeFilter, root.filters))
```

However, this doesn't reset to the "default", this clears everything. You'd have to then add a `StreamHandler` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Note that in Python3 `map` is lazy and you'll have to wrap it in `list` or use a for loop. Otherwise the statement is a no-op.

Comment: And it also help to close the handlers before removing them, to avoid files still being locked.

Comment: I am having following error `AttributeError: 'RootLogger' object has no attribute 'getLogger'`, if I do restart withing the `ipdb` @Alec Thomas

Answer (score 12):

A more complete solution that doesn't invalidate any loggers. Should work, unless some module does something strange like holding a reference to a filterer or a handler.

```
def reset_logging():
    manager = logging.root.manager
    manager.disabled = logging.NOTSET
    for logger in manager.loggerDict.values():
        if isinstance(logger, logging.Logger):
            logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
            logger.propagate = True
            logger.disabled = False
            logger.filters.clear()
            handlers = logger.handlers.copy()
            for handler in handlers:
                # Copied from `logging.shutdown`.
                try:
                    handler.acquire()
                    handler.flush()
                    handler.close()
                except (OSError, ValueError):
                    pass
                finally:
                    handler.release()
                logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

Needless to say, you must setup your logging *after* running `reset_logging()`.