# How do I monkeypatch a module BEFORE importing it (to override something in its __init__.py)?

Tags: python, import, module, monkeypatching

I'm using a third party library, `floris`.

In `floris/__init__.py` they have:

```py
from . import logging_manager

logging_manager._setup_logger()
```

This completely destroys my carefully crafted logging configuration, and does all sorts of things like adding opinionated log formatters onto the root logger.

In my code, I do:

```py
from floris.simulation.turbine import Turbine

def run():
    do_stuff_with_floris = Turbine()
```

Submitting an upstream fix will happen, but isn't a quick process so to my mind the clearest thing to do is to monkeypatch `floris`. But the problem is, the function I want to patch gets called *in the module import*.

```py
# I can't do 
class MonkeyLoggingManager:
    def _setup_logging(self):
        pass

floris.logging_manager = MonkeyLoggingManager()
# ^^^^ Because this is not imported yet.
from floris.simulation.turbine import Turbine
```

Is it even possible to monkeypatch a module either before, or at the point of, importing it?

Comment: would thins help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034393/import-side-effects-on-logging-how-to-reset-the-logging-module Conceptually resetting the root logger after import of floris?

Comment: I just checked the FLORIS source code, and it looks like this issue has *already* been fixed. The problematic code has been gone since 3.0.

Comment: @user2357112 it has, that's correct but I have a much wider system validated with Floris v2 so unfortunately it's not as simple as that :(

Comment: @JonSG It's possible to reset the logger post-import, yes, but I'm using a framework for creating scientific microservices (octue) which handles logging setup prior to import of the core module, so it's a hassle (different logging config i handled depending on where the code is executed, etc). I suppose I could essentially copy all the handlers prior to the import then reapply them immediately afterward!